# display modal popup using for loop in query

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one requirement i want display modal popup window based on for
     loop using jquery i tried with the following query. Here i want display modal 
     popup based on flag value. For example Flag value 3 then popup will be display 
     and when we click on close again it will be displayed upto 3 times. But the following
     code will be displayed only one time.

```
<script type="text/javascript> 
  for(var i=0;i<flag;i++){ 
     jQuery(function ($){   
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
     });
  }
</script>
```

please give me a suggestion to solve this issue  !

Comment: why you want to displayed same popup 3 times.?

Comment: I agree with @HarshitTailor what is it you want with 3 same popups?

Comment: That is Client Requirement and message will be changed for every popup dynamically @Harishit Tailor

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it with a loop because it's an async task. I'd do:

```
var flag = 3;
(function openModal(times){
    if(times <= 0) return;  //End
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
      'close': function(){         //Assuming this is the syntax for close callback
           openModal(times-1);
       }
    });    
})(flag);
```

Another way, longer but maybe more understandable:

```
var flag = 3;
function openModal(){
   if(flag > 0){
     $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
       'close': function(){         //Assuming this is the syntax for close callback
           flag--;           
           openModal();           
        }
      });    
   }else{
       alert("Finished closing all the times needed!");
   }
};
openModal();
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: i tired above code but i am not getting any popup messages can you tell any other possibility @Edgar Villegas Alvarado